# Inserting data in postgreSQL database by Django model

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, django-csrf

i found an error when i insert data to **postgres** database by **django** model,when i put csrf package in comment then my oage was found successfully else its shows an **forbidden error** my code and screen shot is below

```
here is html file:

{% extends "homepage/index.html" %}
{% block title %}
Contact
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
This is Contact us Page.
<form action="/ins/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Created Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Updated Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="uid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Published Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pid"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="fdfdf" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
        <td><input type="submit" value="Insert"></td>
        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>     
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
views.py file:

def ins(request):
#c = {}
#c.update(csrf(request))
cr = request.POST.get('cid','')
up = request.POST.get('uid','')
tit = request.POST.get('tid','')
tx = request.POST.get('txid','')
pd = request.POST.get('pid','')
e = Entry(created=cr,updated=up,title=tit,text=tx,published=pd)
e.save()
    return HttpResponse("Inserted SuccessFuly..")
```

Comment: You don't need to put ```<input type="hidden" name="fdfdf" value="{{ csrf_token }}">```, just ```{{csrf_token}}``` will do.

Comment: Importantly, it should also be noted you are not doing any form of validation on the data you are inserting into the database, which is unwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing so much work by hand. Here's what you need to do:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from your_app.models import Entry

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from your_app.forms import EntryForm

def ins(request):
    form = EntryForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'form': form})


# index.html

{# code shortened for demonstration purposes #}

<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {{ form.as_table }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>
```

Pulling form values directly out of the request.POST dictionary without passing them through your form's validation is a horrible idea - please don't do that.

Comment: same error dear forbidden 
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: why we put (.) here action="." ?

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way csrf verification could fail given the example code. Using . For the form action will make the form post to the same url the view was loaded on.

Comment: ok its version problem ,its solved now and verified successfully

Comment: What sort of version problem? With Django itself?